# Probability of occurrence after Latin Hypercube sampling and then random sampling

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, random, latin-square

I am using Latin Hypercube sampling to obtain numbers from a Normally Distributed set of data, so that I get a uniform spread of numbers across the Normal Distribution. I then select a number at random from the array of Latin Hypercube samples. What is the probability of drawing a *specific* number at the end of this process?

Is it also correct to take the probability of a particular element in a Latin Hypercube as being $\dfrac {1}{\text {number of elements in the Hypercube}}$ ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thinking might be the following. The LHS sampling generates a n-dimensional grid with equal volume per cell. The cell volume can calculated as

$$
v = \frac{\prod_i^n r_i}{K^n}
$$

where $r_i=(x_{max_i} - x_{min_i})/\delta x_i$ is the range of dimension $i$, $K$ is the number of partitions, and $n$ is the number of dimensions. Variable $\delta x_i\leq 1$ is a step/error, which for integer number is 1.

Then the probability of finding a specific number amongst the samples should obey the logic: $ p \rightarrow 1 $ as $v \rightarrow v_{min}$, provided the point of interest is in the cell and each cell has the same prob. density. Variable $v_{min}$ stands for the minimum volume (or area in 2d) to capture/represent a unique point within, $v_{min}=\prod_i^n \delta x_i$.

Therefore, the probability of interest is a product of probabilities of two independent events: prob. for the point to be in the cell and prob. the point in the cell to be selected:

$$
p = \frac{K}{K^n}\frac{v_{min}}{v} = K \frac{ v_{min}}{\prod_i^n r_i}=  K \frac{ \prod_i^n \delta x_i^2}{\prod_i^n (x_{max_i} - x_{min_i})}
$$

Now, the probability of drawing number X from the samples could be estimated as

$$
p' = \frac{ p } {K} 
$$